# How to add two numeric computed properties together in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have two computed properties that will return numbers. How can I create another computed property that will return the sum of the two? Doing a simple this.get("prop1") + this.get("prop2") does not seem to to work. Only the value of the first property is returned.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the example
I found my problem is that one of the properties is actually an array. I just need the first item in the array so I did this.get('prop1.firstObject') .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this

http://jsbin.com/enEvunih/2/edit

```
  propA: function(){
    return 1;
  }.property(),

  propB: function(){
    return 2;
  }.property(),

  propC: function(){
    return this.get('propA') + this.get('propB');
  }.property('propA', 'propB'),
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one of the property was returning an array. Did not notice that for some reason.

Thanks for the answer though.